# How to split child categories into columns using wp_nav_menu()?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, navigation

I have a navigation menu which uses Wordpress' `wp_nav_menu()` function to first render the parent categories and all child categories to that category in a drop down sub menu. The markup looks as follows:

```
<li id="menu-item-256" class="category-electronics menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
    <a class="expander-btn" href="#">
    <div class="drop-down">
        <div class="arrow left"></div>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-272" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-270" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-269" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-268" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-267" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-266" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-262" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
            <li id="menu-item-261" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category">
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

I would like to be able to split the child categories up in columns (with 5 or 6 links in each column), but don't really know how to go about to accomplish this. I've spent almost 30 hours on this now to no avail, so any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function to format a decent HTML markup for columns as many as you want.

There is also another solution possible by using only CSS. Just put width on the `<ul>` and width of the `<li>`(the `<ul>` should be twice as wide as the `<li>`) and float the `<li>` elements inside.

- First `<li>` in the first column
- Second `<li>` in the second column
- Third `<li>` in the first column
- etc.